# Number of Null and non-null values for each column in SQL for a given table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the number of null values, non-null values, total rows for each column in a table named `StudentScore`.

**Code to create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE StudentScore
    ( Student_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
      Student_Name NVARCHAR (50),
      Student_Score INT  ) 
    GO  INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (1,'Ali', NULL)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (4,NULL, 770)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (5,'John', 1240)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (7,'Goerge', NULL)
```

**Code to find number of null, non null, total rows for each column in the table:**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  FORMATMESSAGE('SELECT table_schema = ''%s''
                        ,table_name = ''%s''
                        ,table_col_name = ''%s'' 
                        ,row_num = COUNT(*)
                        ,row_num_non_nulls = COUNT(%s)
                        ,row_num_nulls = COUNT(*) - COUNT(%s)
                 FROM %s.%s', 
     QUOTENAME(dbo),
     QUOTENAME(StudentScore),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(dbo),
     QUOTENAME(StudentScore),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)), ' UNION ALL' + CHAR(13)
               ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY dbo, StudentScore)

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'YES';

SELECT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
```

**I am getting below errors:**

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'dbo'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'StudentScore'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'dbo'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'StudentScore'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'dbo'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'StudentScore'.
```

**Result I need:**

```
| table_schema  |   table_name    | table_col_name   | row_num  | row_num_non_nulls  | row_num_nulls |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
| [dbo]         | [StudentScore]  | [Student_Name]   |       7  |                 6  |             1 |
| [dbo]         | [StudentScore]  | [Student_Score]  |       7  |                 5  |             2 |
```

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` does not contains such column name like `dbo` or `StudentScore`

Comment: If you wanted `find number of null, non null, total rows for each column in the table` Why don't you query the table `StudentScore` directly ?

Comment: Please help how to do that....dont know it

Comment: Please show us the result that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` does not contain columns `dbo` and `StudentTable`, so using `QUOTENAME(dbo)`, `QUOTENAME(StudentScore)` and `WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY dbo, StudentScore)` is an eror.

If you want to count the `NULL` and `NOT NULL` values for `NULLABLE` columns for one specific table, the statement should be:

```
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
    FORMATMESSAGE('
       SELECT table_schema = ''%s''
       ,table_name = ''%s''
       ,table_col_name = ''%s'' 
       ,row_num = COUNT(*)
       ,row_num_non_nulls = COUNT(%s)
       ,row_num_nulls = COUNT(*) - COUNT(%s)
       FROM %s.%s
       ', 
       QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_SCHEMA),
       QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME),
       QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME),
       QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME),
       QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME),
       QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_SCHEMA),
       QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME)
     ), 
     ' UNION ALL '
) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE 
   (c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND 
   (c.TABLE_NAME = 'StudentScore') AND
   (c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES');

SELECT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: `DECLARE @sql varchar(max) SELECT @sql =STRING_AGG(FORMATMESSAGE('SELECT table_scheme=''%s'',table_name=''%s'',column_name=''%s'',total_values_in_columns=COUNT(*), 
NON-NULL-COLUMNS=COUNT(%S),NULL_COLUMNS=Count(*) - count(%s)
FROM %s.%s',QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA), QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),QUOTENAME(INFORMATION_SCHEMA), QUOTENAME(COLUMNS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
   (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND   (TABLE_NAME = 'Orders') AND (IS_NULLABLE = 'YES');SELECT @sql;EXEC(@sql);`

Comment: 1. why have we not put information_schema and columns in Quotename?  2. What is the use of CHAR(13) and `UNION ALL`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor 1) When you build a dynamic statement, as a general rule, you should use `QUOTENAME` with schema, table and column names to make a _string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier_ and prevent sql injection issues.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor 2) You are not using the statement from the answer. Your statement is wrong. It's important to use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate each statement into one complex statement. Function `STRiNG_AGG` expects two parameters, so `' UNION ALL' + CHAR(13)` is very important here, because this is the second paramter for the `STRING_AGG` call. With `UNION ALL` you are concatenating each separate statement.

Comment: why cant we include information_schema and columns in quotenames

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Because [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the name of a system information schema view, not a text literal.

Comment: Then why there is `from %s.%s`...... how to fill that %s and %s

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Because you are building a dynamic statement, using aggregation (with `STRING_AGG` and `UNION ALL + CHAR(13)` as a separator). Each single statement is build with `FORMATMESSAGE` and has 7 placeholders (`%`). The last 7 parameters in `FORMATMESSAGE` are the actual values for the placeholders.

Comment: where are the palceholders for `from %s.%s`? that is my question....

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor `QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)` and `QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)` - the last 2 parameters in the `FORMAT_MESSAGE` call.  You may remove `CHAR(13)` and use an alias for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view (see the updated answer).